# Search text file for words cont

Tags: list, python-3.x, search, input

I have a list of words from a text file and a list of seven letters that are entered as input from a user. How can I search the list of words for words that contain at least five of the seven letters of input?

Answer (score 0):

what about ?

if any(word in 'some one long two phrase three' for word in list_ if word.isalpha() and len(word) == 7)